# selectable dialogbox

Tags: android

open message box and long click on a message , as you can see , a new dialog box will be shown with some selectable items like View Contact and Delete Thread , how can I make a dilogbox like it , so when I can put some items and make some events for each one .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Android tutorial page for dialogue boxes with sample code for each type: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

There are a few different built-in layouts and you can have your own custom dialogue too, depending on what suits your needs